# EF Core 'no such table' when using base class

Tags: entity-framework-core

For starters, *I have an entity structure that I cannot change*.

My Database has a `Person` table and a `Users` table (for the context of this question).

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Person] ...
CREATE TABLE [User] ...
```

My entities are using some inheritance

```cs
public abstract PersonBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // person meta data
}

public class Person : PersonBase
{
    // additional data for app 1
}

public class User 
{
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public PersonBase Person { get; set; } // I cannot change this #sadpanda
}
```

When I try and configure the relationship

```cs
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
    }
}
```

And subsequently try to query it, EF Core generates the following query

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM "User" AS "e"
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT "e0".*
    FROM "PersonBase" AS "e0"
    WHERE "e0"."Deleted" = 0
) AS "t" ON "e"."PersonId" = "t"."Id"
....
```

And I get an error

> SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: PersonBase'.

Is there any way to get this configured so that when I try to hydrate the `User.Person`, EF will use the `Person` table from the database even though the entity type is `PersonBase`?

note: to re-iterate, I cannot change the Entity structure, but I have full control over my Entity Configuration.

I tried setting up my configuration with strings

```cs
builder.HasOne("Person").WithMany().HasForeignKey("PersonId");
```

But then it complained about shadow state

> Entity type 'Person' is in shadow-state. A valid model requires all entity types to have corresponding CLR type.

Comment: *"I have an entity structure that I cannot change"* Then you are out of luck, because for EF `PersonBase` is not an entity. And if you map it as entity, then EF Core will expect discriminator column because of TPH.

Comment: @IvanStoev I might be able to add Attributes to the entities, but that's about as far as I could go.

Comment: Attributes, fluent - it doesn't matter. The navigation property **type** is important, and currently there is no way you can remap it to another type. For non navigation properties there are value converters, but no similar functionality for navigations (hence relationships).

Comment: thank you. I am in communication with the team that manages those entities, and have asked them to consider a change from `IS A` to `HAS A`.